# Malformed Packet on ICMP python

Tags: python, checksum, packet, icmp, malformed

How i can create a frame icmp
I mark malformet packet on python

1. import socket, struct, uuid, subprocess, fcntl, time,random
2. List item

from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify from datetime import datetime
    tarRed = raw_input('Ingrese nombre de Tarjeta de Red Utilizada: ')
    subprocess.call(['ifconfig', tarRed, 'promisc']) pt = 0x0800 s =
    socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(pt))
    s.bind((tarRed, pt))
    #GETCheck def getchecksum(ip_header,size):  cksum = 0   pointer = 0     while size > 1:         cksum += int((str("%02x" % (ip_header[pointer],))
    + str("%02x" % (ip_header[pointer+1],))), 16)   size -= 2   pointer += 2    #if size: #This accounts for a situation where the header is odd
            #cksum += int(ip_header[pointer])           cksum = (cksum >> 16) +
    (cksum & 0xffff)    cksum += (cksum >>16)       return (~cksum) &
    0xFFFF def _checksum(data):     #calculate the header sum
        ip_header_sum = sum(struct.unpack_from("6H", data))     #add the carry
        ip_header_sum = (ip_header_sum & 0xFFFF) + (ip_header_sum >> 8 &
    0xFFFF)     ip_header_sum = ~ip_header_sum & 0xFFFF     return
    ip_header_sum def i_checksum(checksum_packet):  total = 0   num_words
    = len(checksum_packet) / 2  for chunk in struct.unpack("!%sH" % num_words, checksum_packet[0:num_words*2]):         total += chunk  if
    len(checksum_packet) % 2:       total += ord(checksum_packet[-1]) << 8
        total += total >> 16    return (~total + 0xffff & 0xffff)

```
def checksum(source_string):    sum = 0     countTo =
(len(source_string)/2)*2    count = 0   while count<countTo:
            thisVal = ord(source_string[count + 1])*256 + ord(source_string[count])         sum = sum + thisVal         sum = sum &
0xffffffff
            count = count + 2   if countTo<len(source_string):      sum = sum + ord(source_string[len(source_string) - 1])      sum = sum &
0xffffffff  sum = (sum >> 16)  +  (sum & 0xffff)    sum = sum + (sum
>> 16)  answer = ~sum   answer = answer & 0xffff    #answer = answer >> 8 | (answer << 8 & 0xff00)  return answer def
checksuma(source_string):   sum = 0     countTo =
(len(source_string)/2)*2    count = 0   while count<countTo:
            thisVal = ord(source_string[count + 1])*256 + ord(source_string[count])         sum = sum + thisVal         sum = sum &
0xffffffff
            count = count + 2   if countTo<len(source_string):      sum = sum + ord(source_string[len(source_string) - 1])      sum = sum &
0xffffffff  sum = (sum >> 16)  +  (sum & 0xffff)    sum = sum + (sum
>> 16)  answer = ~sum   answer = answer & 0xffff    answer = answer >> 8 | (answer << 8 & 0xff00)   return answer def ultimo(str):
    csum = 0
    countTo = (len(str) / 2) * 2
    count = 0

    while count < countTo:
        thisVal = ord(str[count+1]) * 256 + ord(str[count])
        csum = csum + thisVal
        csum = csum & 0xffffffff
        count = count + 2

    if countTo < len(str):
        csum = csum + ord(str[len(str) - 1])
        csum = csum & 0xffffffff

    csum = (csum >> 16) + (csum & 0xffff)
    csum = csum + (csum >> 16)
    answer = ~csum
    answer = answer & 0xffff
    answer = answer >> 8 | (answer << 8 & 0xff00)
    return answer
#GETCheck
#MACs adst='ffffffffffff' mac_destino = unhexlify(adst) ma = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) info =
fcntl.ioctl(ma.fileno(), 0x8927,  struct.pack('256s', tarRed[:15]))
asrc = ''.join(['%02x:' % ord(char) for char in info[18:24]])[:-1]
sd = asrc.split(':') asrc = sd[0]+sd[1]+sd[2]+sd[3]+sd[4]+sd[5]
mac_origen = unhexlify(asrc)
#MACs cabEther = struct.pack('!6s6sh',mac_destino,mac_origen,pt)
#datosIP
#version = '4'
#IHL = '5' tipoServicio = unhexlify('00') longitudT = struct.pack('!BB',00,24) identificador = struct.pack('!BB',00,01)
flag_Pos = 0x4000 tiempoVida = 05 ptIP = unhexlify('01') SCC = 0
#IPs ip = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) ipO= str( socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(ip.fileno(),0x8915,struct.pack('256s',
tarRed[:15]))[20:24])) ipO1 = ipO.split('.') ipOr =
struct.pack("!BBBB",int(ipO1[0]),int(ipO1[1]),int(ipO1[2]),int(ipO1[3]))
ipD = raw_input('Ingrese la direccion IP destino:  ') ipD1 =
ipD.split('.') ipDest =
struct.pack("!BBBB",int(ipD1[0]),int(ipD1[1]),int(ipD1[2]),int(ipD1[3]))
#IPs
#datosIP cabIP = struct.pack('!1s1s2s2shB1sH4s4s',unhexlify('45'),tipoServicio,longitudT,identificador,flag_Pos,tiempoVida,ptIP,SCC,ipOr,ipDest)
SCC = checksum(cabIP) cabIP =
struct.pack('!1s1s2s2shB1sH4s4s',unhexlify('45'),tipoServicio,longitudT,identificador,flag_Pos,tiempoVida,ptIP,socket.htons(SCC),ipOr,ipDest)
#datosIcmp tipo = 8 codigo = 0x00 check = 0x0000 identificador = int((id(1) * random.random()) % 65535) secuencia = 0x0000
#datos = 'qwertyasdfghzxcvbn0102030405060708091011121314151617181920' datos =
1 * 'Q'
#datosIcmp cabIcmp = struct.pack('!bbHHh',tipo,0,0,identificador,1) my_checksum = ultimo(cabIcmp + datos) cabIcmp =
struct.pack('!bbHHh',tipo,0,socket.htons(my_checksum),identificador,1)
cabIcmp = cabIcmp + datos tiempo = datetime.now() print tiempo for i
in range(15):   s.send(cabEther + cabIP + cabIcmp,0)
```

Comment: What is that mess of code? Even if you fix the formatting so we can actually read it, what is it supposed to _do_, and _why_? How is it related to the question? And what exactly are you stuck on?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is barely understandable. It appears you're asking how to create an ICMP ECHO packet since the packet you are creating in the listed code is reported as malformed by your system. I'll try to answer why your code won't work.

First, the socket type you're using is incorrect. You need type 1, not 8. This can be done easily enough with the third parameter:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
```

(Note you'll need root or administrator privileges to make this call.)

Second, after creating the socket, you'll need to create the ICMP header. An ICMP header consists of the following structure:

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 0 |     Type      |     Code      |          Checksum             |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 4 |                         REST OF HEADER                        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Notice the second four bytes "REST OF HEADER". This second set of four bytes depends on the TYPE/CODE in the first two bytes. For example, if TYPE is 0 and CODE is 0, it means you're dealing with an echo reply, and as such, the second four bytes will become 2-byte **Identifier** and 2-byte **Sequence Number** fields, starting at offset 4 and ending at offset 7 as the picture shows:

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 0 |     Type      |     Code      |          Checksum             |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 4 |           Identifier          |        Sequence Number        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 8 |     Data ...
   +-+-+-+-+-
```

To create this header, I'm going to use type 8, the echo request structure, as such (note that bytes 4-5 and 6-7 in this creation is just for illustration, typically this would be different values other than zero):

```
icmp = struct.pack(">BBHHH", 8, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

On this initial creation of the header, the checksum is zero. What we now need is to actually calculate the checksum (with this zero value), and THEN recreate the header with this new checksum value:

```
icmp = struct.pack(">BBHHH", 8, 0, cksum(icmp), 0, 0)
```

But this is where your code is incorrect again. The implementation of `i_checksum()` is wrong. To fix, I'll leave it to you to figure it out. The checksum is called 1's complement, and there are numerous online articles about it, as well as C code on Linux systems that implement it.

Once you have the header and its correct checksum (important because your system won't send the packet if incorrect), you simply then send it somewhere:

```
s.sendto(icmp, (SOME_REMOTE_HOST, 0))
```

And then receive replies if any:

```
s.recvfrom(1500)
```

(Note I chose 1500 bytes as that is the MTU of an IP frame, and it is thus unlikely a reply will be bigger than this, though it is certainly possible.)

*AND AT THIS POINT, YOUR CODE TOTALLY FAILS* -- simply because you do not have code which does the last two steps, let alone additional code to handle what to do with replies and struct-parsing of the header fields.

As for the other two functions you've defined, they're odd. One of them seems to imply it is dealing with link layer fields -- which is never the case on sockets as sockets only deal in IP layer and above -- while the other seems to be an attempt at calculating a checksum...albeit incorrectly (again).

In short, as **abarnert** implied, please clarify (and add some more) code AND your question.